# dynamic page content with primefaces

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces, javabeans

I'm creating a web page.  The content should change according to user selection.

I require 2 radio buttons which give the option to select one day and many days (start date and end date) if one day selected page should display one calender to select date else two calenders to select start date and end date I tried to use rendered propety with ajax but I can't view calenders how could i do this

my xhtml

```
<h:form id="f1">
                    <p:growl id="createmsg"/>  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                        <p:panel id="add_visitor_details_pnl" style="width:100%"> 
                            <h:panelGrid id="grid" columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                                <h:outputText value="Organization :" />
                                <p:selectOneMenu  editable="true" value="#{visitorBean.organization}"  style="width:160px"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{visitorBean.organizations}" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                <h:outputText value="Visitor Name :" />
                                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{visitorBean.name}"  style="width:160px"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{visitorBean.names}" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                <h:outputText value="Visitor ID :" />
                                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{visitorBean.id}"  style="width:160px"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{visitorBean.ids}" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>                                                         
                                <h:outputText value="Purpose :" />
                                <p:inputTextarea id="purpose_it" value="#{visitorBean.purpose}" required="true" autoResize="false"
                                             requiredMessage="Enter Purpose" rows="10" cols="50"/>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                            <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="10">
                                <p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio" value="#{visitorBean.option}" >  
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Create a one day appointment" itemValue="1" />  
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="create a day period appointment" itemValue="2" />
                                    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{visitorBean.selectDayType()}" 
                                            update=":f1:add_visitor_details_pnl"     />
                                </p:selectOneRadio>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                            <h:panelGrid id="date" columns="3" cellpadding="10">
                                <h:outputText id="date1" value="Date" rendered="#{visitorBean.cal1}"/> 
                                <p:calendar id="calender_Cal1" value="#{visitorBean.date_time}" 
                                            pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"  rendered="#{visitorBean.cal1}" 
                                            required="true" requiredMessage="Enter Date Time"/>
                                <p:calendar id="calender_Cal2" value="#{visitorBean.date_time}" 
                                            pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"  rendered="#{visitorBean.cal2}" 
                                            required="true" requiredMessage="Enter Date Time"/>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                                <p:commandButton id="submit_visitor_Btn" value="Create"                                                         
                                                 action="#{visitorBean.submitVisitorData()}"
                                                 update=":f1:visitor_dataTable,:f1:grid,:f1:createmsg"/>



                            </h:panelGrid>
```

my ajax mthod

```
public void selectDayType(){
    if(option =="1")
        cal1 = "true";
    else if(option =="2"){
        cal1="true";
        cal2="true";            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the calendars with a:

```
<p:outputPanel  id="someId" >
...
</p:outputPanel>
```

[Primefaces - Output Panel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/outputPanel.jsf)

Comment: Btw what types are cal1 and cal2 variables? They look like Strings to me and i guess they should be of type boolean